# Unable to import Spring RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to implement a REST based MongoDB service through Spring, but I have run into some trouble. I cannot import a certain library.

I have this in my class:

```
package main;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

But the `import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;`
is not working for some reason and is giving me the error: `The import org.springframework.data.rest cannot be resolved`

This is my maven pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>UserRegistrationServices</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserRegistrationServices</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Get the dependencies of a web application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Support -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also, I am directly following this guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/

How can this be resolved? Thanks

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 17):

Edit your pom.xml.... and add these lines inside `<dependencies></dependencies>`...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: now it is not 2.1.8, but 2.1.0 
          
          
`<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem on `1.3.6.RELEASE`.

It said,

> org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource cannot be resolved to a type

So I set the version of spring-boot as `1.2.8.RELEAS`, now I solve the problem.

My current spring-boot's pom.xml is below.

```
....

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this error message. In my case was the cause a refresh problem in the IDE (Intellij). 
Deleting the line with the annotation (*@RepositoryRestResource*) and reinsert it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I also had tried to follow the same from https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/
For me, this issue got resolved after I added the version from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest/2.3.0.RELEASE
to be more precise and clear, I added this in the pom.xml file to solve this issue. Maybe if you add the version it will start working!

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```